# Recording guitar and vocals (condenser mic) simultaneously

Tags: microphone, guitar, power, interface, phantom

I'd like to ask if running a condenser mic on an interface with 48v phantom power enabled (such as the focusrite pro14) at the same time with a guitar in the other input, causes any issues. There is only one button available for phantom power and it is shared across both inputs.

Comment: It _should_ also be fine without a DI (using the other input as 1/4" hi-Z for the guitar), but I don't have any proof.

Answer (score 1):

It will be fine if you run it through a DI box for guitar.

[B&H DI Box](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Direct-Boxes/ci/2484/N/3992462079)